# Can a VkSurfaceKHR represent only a whole window? Or also a portion of a window (ie some rectangular widget)?

Tags: vulkan

Using the vulkan API I can create a VkSurfaceKHR from a window. Of course, I do not want to be rendering to memory, but rather render on the GPU and have that replace a portion of the screen (of a connected monitor) that corresponds to this (window) surface.

In fact, since you can make that surface transparent, I am assuming that the GPU has a buffer for the whole desktop (possibly spanning multiple monitors) and blends a rendered surface image with this "desktop" buffer to get it on my monitor(s).

Nowhere in that story it seems important that the surface coincides exactly with a "window" of whatever window manager I might be running.

Yet, it seems that all I can do is get a VkSurfaceKHR for an **entire** window.

Is it not possible to get an arbitrary rectangle inside a window to be this surface (or for that matter, of my desktop)?

If not, why not? What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use VkViewport or offsets in vkCmdCopyImage()? The surfaces are important because pixels of different windows may overlap, in which case an application could draw above some other window if it was drawing directly to the screen; at the same time, switching to a background window needs to load its image from somewhere. VkSurfaceKHR is the abstraction for the surface of the platform you use; if the platform lets you create an object that is just a part of a window/desktop, you should be able to use it.

Comment: @user369070 Of course, when any part of a window is brought to the top again, after being overwritten by another window - then that part has to be redrawn; the application is probably keeping a buffer up to date (by drawing to it) that can be used instantly to refresh that portion of the screen. However, I wish to mix the 2D interface with a 3D widget - or at least am investigating if that is even possible. In that case the 3D widget only covers a part of the window, just like any other widget. In that case it seems strange if the 3D API requires you take a surface that covers the whole window

Comment: I don't see anything strange with it. Just use the viewport to pick where you draw... Also, alpha sometimes works with windowing systems. Oh, did you know that in Windows buttons are actually just tiny windows?

Comment: I am not clear what you call "window" here. Typically in modern OS an application can have as many windows\widgets as it wants (and therefore rectangles). You can create a Vulkan surface from any `HWND` or `xcb_window_t`, which may represent only part of the "main window" in the first place.

Comment: Yes thanks. And now my question, which was asked 17 days before that one, is marked as [duplicated] :/. But ok. It answered my question :p