# Vulkan Rendering - Portion of Surface

Tags: vulkan

How to render a vulkan framebuffer(vkImage) in a portion of Surface?
When I draw in framebuffer, vulkan clear all surface with vkColorClear.

The surface has 800x600 but I would like vulkan render 300x200 using a offset 100x100, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you begin a render pass, you provide the `VkRenderPassBeginInfo` object. In this object is the `renderArea` rectangle, which defines the area of each of the attachment images that the render pass will affect. Any pixels of attachments outside of this area are unaffected by render pass operations, including the clear load op and `vkCmdClearAttachments`.

Note that the `renderArea` is subject to the limitations of the render area granularity, as queried from `vkGetRenderAreaGranularity`.

Comment: It sounds a perfect solution. I will try out. Thank you so much.

Comment: The remaining area (swapchain image) is undefined. This undefined area is rendered as black color in the surface. Is there any way to put it transparent or not render this outside area in the surface? @Nicol Bolas

Comment: @BrunoGallego: Swapchain images do not preserve the image data when you present them. So if you need to keep it around, don't render to the swapchain image directly. Render to some image you control and copy a part of it to the swapchain image.

Comment: in this post (  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761401/create-vulkan-surface-for-only-a-portion-of-a-window ) you said to create a child window, however it has to manipulate window always on top window... if you create third window, it will between the main window and this top window... many issues behaviour to be handled.

Comment: @BrunoGallego: What does any of that have to do with swapchains? Or the question you asked, which was about rendering to a particular area of the render targets?

Comment: @NicelBolas I am rendering in a swapchain image! This image has for example 800x600 (the QT main window size). When I create a surface and framebuffer images using swapchain, the images have 800x600. When Vulkan renders, it renders all surface (screen). I would like to render part of this screen (300x200). Using renderArea and viewport do it in the Swapchain Image, however when this image is rastered in the surface, all surface (800x600) is drawn.

Comment: @BrunoGallego: It's important to understand the difference between rendering an image (what Vulkan cares about) and the process of *presenting* a swapchain image (which Vulkan acknowledges is a thing that happens, but is not its job). What you seem to want is the ability to *present* part of a swapchain image. Vulkan has no mechanism for that. If you want to only update part of a viewable image, while preserving the rest, you will *have to* render to an internal image that you partially update, and copy that *entire image* to the swapchain image.

Comment: hmm I see. You could do an VK_EXTENSION to present part image :D  ahahah  I am beginner in Vulkan. I also did want to fetch data from vulkan "framebuffer" and shows in the window due to performance issues. I am goiing to take the "QTWindow Image" and send to vulkan as background. Thank ou so much @NicolBolas

Comment: @BrunoGallego: Extensions are provided by implementations, not by random users of the API.

Comment: I do not think so... LunarG built ValidationLayer Extension and it is very useful. You can do your own extension and submmit to review.

Comment: @BrunoGallego: You can create your own layers, and perhaps expose those through extensions, but you cannot manufacture functionality that doesn't exist in the Vulkan API itself. That is, if Vulkan can't do a thing with the GPU/OS/display system, your layer *also* can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset a window by setting the view rectangle and viewport in the `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo` structure to the subregion you wish to render. You can dynamically configure the viewport at draw time using `vkCmdSetViewport()`.

For `VkCmdClearAttachments()` you can set the clear area via the `pRects` argument (it ignores viewport).

Comment: Clear operations do not care about the viewport transform.

Comment: Added a clarification,  I assumed there would actually be some follow-on rendering though =)